# Coincidentally assigning a string object the same text as another string object makes both point to the same object, inadvertently. Why?

Tags: string, vb.net, object

Consider the following code snippet, especially the comments with respect to the `Is` operator applied to `s1` and `s2`.

```
    Dim s1 As String = "1"
    Dim s2 As String = "2"
    Debug.Print((s1 Is s2).ToString)    'False - as expected
    s1 = s2
    Debug.Print((s1 Is s2).ToString)    'True - as expected
    s1 = "3"
    Debug.Print((s1 Is s2).ToString)    'False - as expected
    s2 = "3"
    Debug.Print((s1 Is s2).ToString)    'True - wth?
    s2 = "4"
    Debug.Print((s1 Is s2).ToString)    'False - as expected
```

The `s2 = "3"` assignment makes `s1` and `s2` identical objects, temporarily. What is the rationale behind this? Is this not potentially dangerous?

Comment: The compiler does that for optimisation purposes. There is never a reason that you should care about which object a `String` reference refers to.  You should only care about whether the contents of two `Strings` are the same.  That's why you should always use `=` to compare `Strings`; so that you test value equality rather than reference equality.  The only time you should use `Is` with `Strings` is when comparing to `Nothing` in order to explicitly detect a null reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's happening is called [***String interning***](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interning).

Since strings are immutable the .NET runtime stores the string objects you create in a table in order to save memory. Every time you declare a pure (*pure* as in declared without performing any operations on it) string in-code it will check if that string is interned. If it is then the .NET runtime will reference the interned instance instead of creating a completely new one.

See the [**`String.IsInterned()` method**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isinterned(v=vs.110).aspx).

> The common language runtime automatically maintains a table, called *the intern pool*, which contains a single instance of ***each unique literal string constant declared in a program***, as well as any unique instance of String you add programmatically by calling the Intern method.

For instance:

```
Dim s1 As String = "a string" 'A pure, constant string.
Dim s2 As String = s1
Dim s3 As String = "this is " & s1 'Not pure: performing string concatenation.
Dim s4 As String = "this is a string"

Console.WriteLine("s1: " & s1)
Console.WriteLine("s2: " & s2)
Console.WriteLine("s3: " & s3)
Console.WriteLine("s4: " & s4)

Console.WriteLine("s1 Is s2: " & (s1 Is s2)) 'True
Console.WriteLine("s3 Is s4: " & (s3 Is s4)) 'False, s3 has not been interned and is its own instance.
```

**Online test: http://ideone.com/YtkLTz**

Comment: "So every time you create a "new" string it will check if that string is already interned." - that's not true.

Comment: @Enigmativity : Why not? Does it only intern constant strings? **EDIT:** Yes it seems so, I misinterpreted MSDN. Thanks for the heads up!

Comment: It only interns strings at compile-time or if explicitly interned at run-time. There's no check for existing interned strings. Try this code `object x = "a1"; object y = "a" + 1.ToString(); Console.WriteLine(x == y);` - it prints `False`. Change it to `object x = "a1"; object y = "a1"; Console.WriteLine(x == y);` and it prints `True`.

Comment: @Enigmativity : Yes, I understood. I added a code example to the answer as well (writing from my phone so it took me a little while to update). Thanks again!

Comment: @Enigmativity and Visual Vincent, thanks for your time to make clear to me what went on behind the scenes.

Comment: @Herb : Glad to be of help! :)